# Reload chart on api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, chart.js

I'm trying to reload the data on a bar chart from chart.js, but im not able to.

This is the chart:

```
<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  props: ["chartdata"],
  data: () => ({
   
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false
    }
  }),
  computed: {
    chartData: function() {
      return this.data;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    data: function() {
      this._chart.destroy();
      this.renderChart(this.data, this.options);
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
  }
}
</script>
```

This is how I implement it:

```
<chart
:chartdata="chartdata"
:options="options"/>
```

After getting the data from the api and form the chartdata I try to trigger the watch by updating the container data that I'm sending like this:

```
const cd = {
     labels: labels,
     datasets: [{
         label: '# of Votes',
         data: data
     }]}
     this.chartdata = cd
}
```

But It's not working and I don't know why.

Comment: Your prop is named "chartdata" but your watcher is watching "data". You also pass `this.data` to `this.renderChart` instead of `this.chartdata`. Otherwise this should be working fine. You don't need the computed property `chartData` though. You don't use it and it returns a nonexistent property.

Answer (score 0):

Neither familiar with the library or vue.js in general, but the documentation says the following about updating the chart...

> Chart.js does not provide a live update if you change the datasets.
> However, vue-chartjs provides two mixins to achieve this.
>
> reactiveProp reactiveData Both mixins do actually achieve the same.
> Most of the time you will use reactiveProp. It extends the logic of
> your chart component and automatically creates a prop named chartData
> and adds a vue watch on this prop. On data change, it will either call
> update() if only the data inside the datasets has changed or
> renderChart() if new datasets were added.

You're not using the mentioned props in the documentation. You can read more it on the [official documentation](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vue-chartjs, the library has its own way to handle reactive data in charts:

```
// ChartBar.js
import { Bar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'], // passed from the parent
  mounted () {
    // this.chartData is created in the mixin (pass it as any prop with :chart-data="data").
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  }
}
```

Now use the component

```
<chart
  :chart-data="chartdata"
  :options="options"
/>
```

You can read more about it here: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts,
there are some caveats